# jquery mobile mobile back with transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm buliding a web app using backbone.js and jquery mobile.
i wanna add a reverse slide effect to all the className "back" button.

the code looks like this,

```
$('.ico_back').live('click', function(event) {
 $.mobile.back();
 return false;
});
```

Does anyone know how to add a reverse effect to `$.mobile.back()` function?

(This is a single-page app, so i can't do this with a tranditional JQM way: like add a simple `data-transition="slide"`)

Comment: set your `.ico-back` element inside an `a` tag and add a `data-rel= back` attribute to it. You can add transitions to it as well using `data-transition="slide"` attribute

Comment: i use backbone.js to changing views between different urls, i set     $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;  so i can only use JQM functions to do page changing

Comment: Also replace `.live` with `.on('click', '.ico-back', function`

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to dynamically change to previous page.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/aCuxa/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ico-back', function () {
 var previous = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]');
 $.mobile.changePage(previous, { 
  transition: 'slide',
  reverse: true });
});
```

**EDIT:**  Based on the code in repo provided, do the following changes to the following block of code.

```
if (this.firstPage) {
 transition = 'slide';
 this.firstPage = false;
}
$.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: transition, reverse:true });
```

Comment: thx for the help, there is no mutilple pages in this project, so the code above causes some error, i'm using the code from this github repo, you can check it https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jquerymobile/blob/master/js/main.js

Comment: TypeError: b.data(...) is undefined

Comment: in that code replace `transition = 'none';` with `transition = 'slide';` and add `reverse: true`

Answer (score 1):

In each element with class `.ico_back` it adds the `data-rel` and `data-transition` attributes. This way you don't have to find which is the previous page or add extra logic inside your code. jQM manages the back page transition for you.

```
$(document)
     .on("pageinit", "#page-id", function () {
         $('.ico_back')
             .each(function (index) {
                 $(this)
                     .attr("data-rel", "back");
                 $(this)
                     .attr("data-transition", "slide");
          });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On the lines of Tolis Emmanouilidis's answer, you could `wrap` your `ico_back` classes with an `a`

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page-id", function () {
    $('.ico_back').wrap($('<a/>', { "data-rel":"back", "data-transition" : "slide" }));
});
```

**NOTE**:
This will be applicable if and only if `ico_back` isnt an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can even use `history.back()` at button click